# getting data from mysql for ember application using node

Tags: mysql, node.js, ember.js

I have a small ember application that gets data from mysql using node. Currently I use the following to fetch the customer data:

```
function handleGet(connection,req,res) {
    var limit = ('undefined' === typeof req.params.limit) ? 200: req.params.limit;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT ' + limit, function handleSql(err, rows) {
        if (err){ logAndRespond(err,res); return; }
        if (rows.length === 0){ res.send(204); return; }
        res.send({customers : rows});
        connection.release();
    });
}
```

however I would not want to have a function for customers, another for users, etc. 
How can I abstract this? 
I could pass the table name to the function,no problem. The problem is that Ember expects the name of the table on the response. So I cannot change the line :

```
res.send({customers : rows});
```

to

```
res.send({tablename : rows});
```

since it sends literally the word 'tablename' rather than content of the variable, like this:
{"tablename":[{"id":1,"status":"n".....}]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other answer already lectured you, here's the solution:

```
function handleGet(connection, req, res) {
    var limit = ('undefined' === typeof req.params.limit) ? 200: req.params.limit;
    var table = req.params.table || return logAndRespond(new Error("Missing table param", res));
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' LIMIT ' + limit, function handleSql (err, rows) {
        if (err){ logAndRespond(err,res); return; }
        if (rows.length === 0){ res.send(204); return; }
        var result = {};
        result[table] = rows;
        res.send(result);
        connection.release();
    });
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Yeah, I know the embedded sql is bad. I am teaching myself ember-node-mysql so I am trying to walk before I run :) If you do have suggestions for a good tutorial or any advice that would be great too.:)

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo that may be preventing it from sending the table name variable value. you have "tablemame" instead of "tablename".

Also, I would strongly suggest you remove actual SQL statements from any Javascript! A hacker could modify your code to run any SQL they wanted.

Comment: actually it was a typo when I was typing the example, sorry about that. So if I do : res.send({tablename : rows});  then the json sent is something like {"tablename":[{"id":1,"status":"n".....}]. I agree about removing the sql, I am currently trying to learn Ember and node, one step at a time :)